# Powershell Log tailer filtering

Tags: powershell, logging, monitoring

I wrote a very basic powershell log tailer script with filters and coloring.
 Everything works perfectly fine except the filtering (by filtering i mean not printing the unneccessary lines). When the script reads a file that is not being written anymore, it filters out lines correctly. But when lines are being in written constantly and the script reads it real time sometimes it prints an empty line instead of nothing.

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "ARMA 3 LOG VIEWER"
$dir = "E:\\SteamLibrary\\steamapps\\common\\Arma 3 Server\\SC"
$filter="*.rpt"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.fullname

function Get-LogColor {
    Param([Parameter(Position=0)]
    [String]$LogEntry)

    process {
        if ($LogEntry.Contains("DEBUG") -or $LogEntry.Contains("[A3XAI Monitor]")) {Return "Green"}
        elseif ($LogEntry.Contains("WARN") -or $LogEntry.Contains("Warn")) {Return "Yellow"}
        elseif ($LogEntry.Contains("ERROR") -or $LogEntry.Contains("Error")) {Return "Red"}
        elseif ($Logentry.Contains("infiSTAR.de")) {Return "Magenta"}
        else {Return "White"}
    }
}

Get-Content $latest.fullname -Wait | where { 
$_ -notmatch "strange convex" -and 
$_ -notmatch "Error: Bone" -and
$_ -notmatch "wrong size" -and
} | ForEach {Write-Host -ForegroundColor (Get-LogColor $_) $_}
```

Comment: Is it possible that this is just an artifact of how the program writes ist logfiles? Maybe it sometimes creates empty lines before writing something in them. What happens when you add `$_ -ne ""` to your where clause? Btw I just noticed that you have an extra  `-and` in there

Comment: that -and wasnt in the original code i just stripped it a bit for clarity, but i'll try '$_ -ne ""' Thanks